# Time converter in Java

Tags: java, beginner, datetime, converting

Can this time converter be written more efficiently? I'm new to Java, and I would like to know.

### main

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
    window wn = new window();
        wn.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        wn.setSize(275, 170);
        wn.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

### time

```
public class time {
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private String ampm;

    public void setTime(int h, int m, String t) {
        hour = ((h>=0 && h<=24) ? h : 0);
        minute = ((m>=0 && m<=60) ? m : 0);
        ampm = t;
    }

    public String to24h() {
        if (ampm == "PM") {
            hour += 12;
        }
        return String.format("%02d:%02d", hour, minute);
    }
}
```

### window

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class window extends JFrame {

    private JLabel label;
    private JTextField hours;
    private JTextField minutes;
    private JTextField output;
    private JButton twelve_button;
    public time timeConvert = new time();
    int tHours;
    int tMinutes;
    private String[] times = {"AM", "PM"};
    private JComboBox combo;
    String tAMPM;

    public window() {
        super("Time Converter");
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        label = new JLabel("Time");
        add(label);

        hours = new JTextField(2);
        add(hours);

        label = new JLabel(":");
        add(label);

        minutes = new JTextField(2);
        add(minutes);

        combo = new JComboBox(times);
        add(combo);

        twelve_button = new JButton("Convert to 24 hours");
        add(twelve_button);

        output = new JTextField(10);
        output.setEditable(false);
        add(output);

        label = new JLabel("It's my 'hello world' of java development!");
        add(label);

        label = new JLabel("by jackwilsdon");
        add(label);

        theHandler handler = new theHandler();

        hours.addActionListener(handler);
        minutes.addActionListener(handler);
        twelve_button.addActionListener(handler);
    }

    private class theHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            if (event.getSource() == twelve_button) {
                if (hours.getText() != null && minutes.getText() != null) {
                    try {
                        tHours = Integer.parseInt(hours.getText());
                        tMinutes = Integer.parseInt(minutes.getText());
                        tAMPM = (String)combo.getSelectedItem();
                        timeConvert.setTime(tHours, tMinutes, tAMPM);
                        if (tHours > 12) {
                            output.setText("Please enter a 12 hour number!");
                        } else if (tMinutes > 60) {
                            output.setText("Please enter a 12 hour number!");
                        } else {
                            output.setText(timeConvert.to24h());
                        }
                    }
                    catch(NumberFormatException nFE) {
                        output.setText("Please enter a number!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You asked about efficiency, which I am not an expert in. However, if you are going to share your code here, it would be nice if you could adapt it to the [Java code style conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html).
In short: you should use [PascalCase](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PascalCase) for your class names, so...

- `Main.java` instead of <del>main.java</del>
- `Time.java` instead of <del>time.java</del>
- `Window.java` instead of <del>window.java</del>

Also, using single-letter names for your parameters is discouraged *(borderline* in the case of the fairly obvious `int h` and `int m`, *bad* in the case of `String t`). Why not `hours`, `minutes`, and `halfOfDaySuffix`? I'm sure you could find an even better term for the latter with a little research.

If you haven't already, make sure you organize your code into one or more package(s), e.g. put `package com.jackwilsdon.TimeConversion;` at the beginning of your files. This helps avoid name clashing problems (for instance with [`java.sql.Time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html)).

In regard to `to24h()`: **Never** compare two Strings with the `==` (reference equals) operator in Java. This will only work in a narrow range of scenarios, read the [full explanation on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus). You need to use the [`String.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method instead.

But while we are at it, you shouldn't be using a `String` to represent AM/PM anyway - it will stop working if you pass in the wrong string, for instance `pm` instead of `PM` by mistake. Instead, restrict the possible values by creating an [`Enum`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html):

```
public enum DayHalf {
    AM,
    PM
}
```

Then (in `Window`), you can change `tAMPM`'s type from `String` to `DayHalf` - the following line will stop working:

```
tAMPM = (String)combo.getSelectedItem();
```

So you need to use `combo = new JComboBox(DayHalf.values());` instead of `combo = new JComboBox(times);` and change the above line to

```
tAMPM = (DayHalf)combo.getSelectedItem();
```

If you are passing in `AM` or `PM`, hours above `12` are not acceptable - neither are minutes above `59`! Hence, your conditions are erroneous; also, silently failing by setting the fields to `0` isn't a robust solution. You should throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the values are out of range.

Your updated `setTime` method would look something like this:

```
public void setTime(int hours, int minutes, DayHalf halfOfDaySuffix) {
    if (hours < 0 || hours > 12 || minutes < 0 || minutes > 59)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("hours or minutes out of allowed range!");
    hour = hours;
    minute = minutes;
    dayHalf = halfOfDaySuffix;
}
```

Regarding your JFrame (`Window.java`, should probably be called `TimeConversionWindow.java`), you should adjust the obviously copied-and-pasted error message:

```
else if (tMinutes > 60) {
    output.setText("Please enter a 12 hour number!");
}
```

to "Please enter less than 60 minutes!" or similar. Note that your condition (`tMinutes > 60`) is incorrect once again and should be changed to `> 59`.

A couple of other adjustments will be required, but they are easy to figure out. I'd argue that performance is nearly irrelevant in this scenario, read up on [bottlenecks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottleneck).

Comment: There are many magic numbers like `0`, `12`, `59` this all should be `final` fields like `maxMinutesInHour` etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
hours.getText() != null && minutes.getText() != null
```

You should also assert if the string is empty using method `hours.getText().isEmpty()`